# In Java, Change/Read String In a Multi-thread Circumstance

Tags: java, multithreading

**Background**

An access token is used by my system to access a platform API.

I have a Thread A to update the access token every 2 min.

Then the other threads who handle front-end requests will use the access token to make API calls.

The platform who provides the access token itself has implemented some token overlap mechanism. That is, an old token will still be available for 30 seconds after a new token is generated.

**Thoughts**

I have an interface like below:

```
public interface AccessTokenService {

    String fetchAccessToken();

    void refreshAccessToken();
}
```

Apparently, the easiest and error-free way to handle it is to make these two methods synchronized. However, since the token providing platform has token overlap built-in. I don't think "synchronized" is needed to make it business right. In addition, since my system highly relies on the API calls, make the methods synchronized would result in a performance drop.

**Question**

My question is, how, under the hood, the JVM handle multi-thread String write/read.

Say, a string accessToken is being changed from "abc" to "def". Meanwhile, a few threads are trying to read the value of accessToken. What are the possible output of the read?

- abc (possible)
- def (possible)
- dbc (?)
- messy content in between the change (?)
- null (?)

Comment: Strings in Java are immutable. That means that a reading thread can either get a reference to the old string `abc` or a reference to the new string `def`

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thanks for the quick reply. I understand strings are immutable in Java. I guess, changing the reference is some byte changes under the hood. Is this byte changes atomic? Is it possible a not completed-changed reference being used when reading the value?

Comment: It isn't at all likely that introducing synchronization into two one-liners just to be sure about this is going to introduce any kind of a performance penalty. If you think otherwise you need to gather some evidence about it. Rather than just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since strings in java are immutable your reading threads can only get either to old token or the new token, but never something mixed together.

Updates to references are always atomar (here too: your reading threads can either read the old reference or the new reference, but not something mixed together).

There is only one point to observe: the field that stores the current token has to be declared as `volatile`, otherwise the reading threads may cache some value that they have seen.

A dummy implementation of your AccessTokenService could look like this:

```
public class DummyAccessTokenService implements AccessTokenService {

    private volatile String currentToken = null;

    @Override
    public String fetchAccessToken() {
        return currentToken;
    }

    private int tokenNumber = 0;

    @Override
    public void refreshAccessToken() {
        currentToken = String.format("Token-%d", tokenNumber++);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this code thread safe.You are using tokenNumber ++ .It can cause race condition.

Comment: @gatisahu no, the `refreshAccessToken` is not thread safe. But for one this is only a dummy implementation that is at most suitable for testing. And second the TO writes that he has a single thread `A` that is refreshing the access tokens. As long as there is only one thread calling `refreshAccessToken` this method does not have to be thread safe.